# two way communication between extension and content javascript files

Tags: firefox-addon

i am trying to accomplish a two way communication request response in my firefox sidebar extension, i have a file named event.js this resides on the content side, i have another file called sidebar.js file which is residing in the xul. I am able to communicate from event.js to sidebar.js file using the dispatchEvent method. my event in turn raises a XMLHttpRequest in sidebar.js file which hits the server and sends back the response. Now, here i am unable to pass the response to the event.js file. I want the response to be accessed in the event.js file. Till now i have achieved only one way communication. Please help me in getting the two way communication.

Code is as follows:

```
// event.js file
// This event occurs on blur of the text box where i need to save the text into the server

function saveEvent() {

 var element = document.getElementById("fetchData");
            element.setAttribute("urlPath", "http://localhost:8080/event?Id=12");
            element.setAttribute("jsonObj", convertToList);
            element.setAttribute("methodType", "POST");
            document.documentElement.appendChild(element);

            var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
            evt.initEvent("saveEvent", true, true);
            element.dispatchEvent(evt);

//Fetching the response over here by adding the listener
document.addEventListener("dispatchedResponse", function (e) { MyExtension.responseListener(e); }, false, true);

}

var MyExtension = {
    responseListener: function (evt) {
        receivedResponse(evt.target.getAttribute("responseObject"));
    }
}

function receivedResponse(event) {
    alert('response: ' + event);
}


// sidebar.js file

window.addEventListener("load", function (event) {

 var saveAjaxRequest = function (urlPath, jsonObj, methodType, evtTarget) {

        var url = urlPath;
        var request = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
        request.onload = function (aEvent) {
            window.alert("Response Text: " + aEvent.target.responseText);
            saveResponse = aEvent.target.responseText;

            //here i am again trying to dispatch the response i got from the server back to the origin, but unable to pass it...

            evtTarget.setAttribute("responseObject", saveResponse);
            document.documentElement.appendChild(evtTarget);

            var evt = document.createEvent("dispatchedRes"); // Error line "Operation is not supported" code: "9"
            evt.initEvent("dispatchedResponse", true, false);
            evtTarget.dispatchEvent(evt);
        };
        request.onerror = function (aEvent) {
            window.alert("Error Status: " + aEvent.target.status);
        };
        //window.alert(methodType + " " + url);
        request.open(methodType, url, true);
        request.send(jsonObj);
    };


this.onLoad = function () {

document.addEventListener("saveEvent", function (e) { MyExtension.saveListener(e); }, false, true);


}


var MyExtension =
        {
            saveListener: function (evt) {
                saveAjaxRequest(evt.target.getAttribute("urlPath"), evt.target.getAttribute("jsonObj"), evt.target.getAttribute("methodType"), evt.originalTarget);
            }
        };


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you moving your `fetchData` element into the sidebar document? You should leave it where it is, otherwise your content code won't be able to receive the event. Also, use the content document to create the event. Finally, `document.createEvent()` parameter for custom events should be `"Events"`. So the code after your `//here i am again trying` comment should look like:

```
evtTarget.setAttribute("responseObject", saveResponse);

var evt = evtTarget.ownerDocument.createEvent("Events");
evt.initEvent("dispatchedResponse", true, false);
evtTarget.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Please note however that your code as you show it here is a huge security vulnerability - it allows *any* website to make *any* HTTP requests and get the result back, so it essentially disables [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). At the very least you need to check that the website talking to you is allowed to do it (e.g. it belongs to your server). But even then it stays a security risk because server response could be altered (e.g. by an attacker on a public WLAN) or your server could be hacked - and you would be giving an attacker access to sensitive data (for example he could trigger a request to mail.google.com and if the victim happens to be logged in he will be able to read all email data). So please make this less generic, only allow requests to some websites.