# Permission denied to call method ChromeWindow.postMessage for iframe inside XUL page

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, cross-domain, xul

I've an extension, and an XUL file inside it (let's call it A). XUL file contains an `<iframe>`, where is loaded some web page (let's call it B). B is loaded from the different domain.
A is parent to B. I want to send a message from within B to A using `window.parent.postMessage()`.
I'm getting the following exception:

> ... permission denied to B to call method ChromeWindow.postMessage

How to fix that error? If there is no way to do that, how can I pass message from B to A?

I am using Firefox 16.0.1 under Windows 7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [two way communication between extension and content javascript files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507022/two-way-communication-between-extension-and-content-javascript-files)

Comment: @Wladimir Palant, here is Firefox issue, related with FF extension development, not with XMLHttpRequest as in your 'possible duplicate' link. The problem is that in order to `postMessage` to some window, one should call `<some window>.postMessage(...)`, and in my case, `some window` is `window.parent`. So, `window.parent.postMessage()` is expected to work, but it doesn't, which makes impossible to use postMessage() for communication between windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar problem, 
it's just I had a html-popup (local) that couldn't send 'postMessage' to my xul-background-task.
I think I got it to work,
strangely enough by initiating a MessageEvent of my own (the very same thing postMessage does)
but with a (I believe obsolete) fallback.. in short: I brewed something together from MDN and other sites ;)

My script in the content:

```
var Communicator = 
{
    postMessage: function(data) 
    { 
        // We need some element to attach the event to, since "window" wont work
        // let's just use a fallback JSON-stringified textnode
        var request = document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(data));
        // and as always attach it to the current contentwindow
        document.head.appendChild(request);
        // Now let's make a MessageEvent of our own, just like window.postMessage would do
        var event = document.createEvent("MessageEvent");
        event.initMessageEvent ("own_message", true, false, data, window.location, 0, window, null);
        // you might want to change "own_message" back to "message" or whatever you like
        //and there we go
        request.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

And instead of window.postMessage(data) now use Communicator.postMessage(data)
that's all!
Now in my overlay there's nothing but our good old

```
addEventListener('own_message', someMessageFunc, false, true);
//or maybe even "message" just like originally
```

Hopefully this will work for you, too (didn't check that on iframes...)

Comment: I also have used the similar approach. Creating events definitely works, see my answer below. Very glad that SO community got a member,  which can really help. Mark as correct for this. But its still unclear to me, why postMessage does not work? For what is it needed if it cannot do this case?

Comment: I guess it's not postMessage that fails, but the target object isn't available. As far as I know firefox tries to hide it's browser.xul as far away from content scripts as possible to avoid malicious interaction; that's why you cannot attach a postMessage to browser.xul (window.parent in your case) from any content window (not that I know), thus we have to create a target which both, the contentwindow and the backgroundscript can interact with, and here my Communicator object drops in.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [`type` of iframe B](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/iframe#a-browser.type)

Edit:

Apparently you must flag your chrome as [contentaccessible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration#contentaccessible), and take into consideration the security.

Comment: I tried!. It is is set to `chrome` and I still get `permission denied`. I've tried also with `type='content'` and got the same error.

Comment: I tried also `contentaccessible=yes` in my chrome.manifest file and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting in case someone faced the same problem.
Succeeded in posting message from within B to A using events as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages).

But it is not answer, because `window.parent.postMessage()` still doesn't work as intended.